# how to find the interval for each activity in dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe

For each User_id I got a list of different events.For instance event1  can occurs different times by the same user.

Which I tried to do is to find the interval for each event belongs to that user and finding the mean of these intervals for each event.

I tried using groupby (['user_id','events'])['time']and aggregation function but the result wasn't as I want.

```
User_id       events           time 

1            A             2012-11-24 09:30:00

1            A             2012-11-24 11:50:00

1            B             2012-11-24 12:15:00

1            B             2012-11-24 16:22:00

1            C             2012-11-24 16:23:40  

1            D             2012-11-25 05:20:00

1            B             2012-11-25 05:24:00

1            A             2012-11-25 15:00:00

2            A             2012-12-20 01:00:00
```

the expected result is:

```
User_id       events           time                     interval

  1           A            2012-11-24 09:30:00           0

              A            2012-11-24 11:50:00          2h20m

              A            2012-11-25 15:00:00          27h10m

              B            2012-11-24 12:15:00           0

              B            2012-11-24 16:22:00          4h7m

              B            2012-11-25 05:24:00          13h2m
```

and then find the mean of these interval for each event.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the times are sorted, you can get the previous event time by doing a groupby and shift

```
df.groupby(['User_id', 'events']).time.shift())
0                   NaT
1   2012-11-24 09:30:00
2                   NaT
3   2012-11-24 12:15:00
4                   NaT
5                   NaT
6   2012-11-24 16:22:00
7   2012-11-24 11:50:00
8                   NaT
```

You can subtract the time from the previous time to get the "elapsed" time that you are looking for.

```
>>> df.time - df.groupby(['User_id', 'events']).time.shift()     
0               NaT
1   0 days 02:20:00
2               NaT
3   0 days 04:07:00
4               NaT
5               NaT
6   0 days 13:02:00
7   1 days 03:10:00
8               NaT
```

Looks like you are defining the first interval as 0, which you can do with fillna.  You can insert this back into the dataframe to get the results you expect.

```
df['interval'] = (df.time - df.groupby(['User_id', 'events']).time.shift()).fillna(pd.Timedelta(0))
```